# Why does cout << "hello" choose the non-member version of the operator<<?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

Today I'm trying to understand this thing related to the **operator<<** and its overloads.

Let's take a look at this code:

```
cout.operator<<("hello");   // +16 overloads -> implicit conversion to void*
cout.operator<<(123);       // +16 overloads

operator<<(cout,"hello");   // +13 overloads
operator<<(cout, 123);      // ERROR: no overload

cout << "hello";            // +13 overloads ---> non-member version!
cout << 123;                // +16 overloads ---> member version!
```

Thanks to Visual Studio's Intellisense, I could detect for each one how many overloads it can provide.

I came to the conclusion:

- Non-member operator<< overloads are **13**
- Member operator<< overloads (for cout) are **16**

**And I got these questions:**

As you can see from the last two lines, when using cout with a const char[] the non-member overload is selected.

- Why isn't there a member operator<< for the cout object which takes a const char[]?

Also, on the fourth line we get an error because there's no non-member operator<< overload which takes an integer.

- Why isn't there a non-member operator<< which takes an integer?

And, last but not least

- Why does `cout << “hello”` choose the non-member version of the operator<< ?

Maybe because there is a particular non-member operator<< overload **which is a good candidate for a const char[]**, rather than the member-operator<< overload which takes a **void***?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Because I'm learning the language in depth and want to know more, maybe?

Comment: I'm actually surprised this hasn't been asked before. No sign of a dupe. Still, seems like a better question for the Working Group's mailing list; there's no practical problem to be solved here. You're just idly wondering why some `operator<<` for IOStreams are members and some are free functions.

Comment: There is no great design behind this, just that some operators have been members - since always. And adding new non-members is a lot easier than adding members. They work the same anyway for `cout << x;`.

Comment: what do the 13 and 16 signify?

Comment: @M.M the number of function overloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't there a member `operator<<` for the `cout` object which takes a `const char[]`?

Character strings are handled separately. Creating member operators for `std::basic_string` would require all streams to have a dependancy on `std::basic_string` functionality, which is not always desirable.  All of the member operators are for built-in language types, but `std::basic_string` is a class instead, so it has non-member operator overloads. One could argue that `const char[]` (which decays to `const char*`) is a built-in type, but `operator<<` streams `const char*` similarly to `std::basic_string`, and it doesn't make sense to split those implementations in two different areas of the library. Functionality for handling character strings, whether using arrays or classes, are usually grouped together.

> Why isn't there a non-member operator<< which takes an integer?

Because there doesn't need to be one.  It already exists as a member operator.  You are not supposed to call member operators *directly* (unless you *need* to, which your  example does not).  You are supposed to just use the operator normally (`stream << ...`) and let overload resolution pick the correct member or non-member operator, based on parameters, scoping, etc.  If you think about it, a non-member overload would cause an ambiquity error. Should `stream << 123` call `stream.operator<<(123)` or `::operator<<(stream, 123)`? There can be only one choice, or the compile fails.

> Why does `cout << “hello”` choose the non-member version of the `operator<<` ?
>   Maybe because there is a particular non-member `operator<<` overload **which is a good candidate for a `const char[]`**, rather than the member-`operator<<` overload which takes a `void*`?

That is exactly why. A typed `const char[]` parameter is a better match for a narrow string literal then an untyped `void*` pointer.  So, if both operators are in scope (and the `const char[]` overload is only in scope if you use `#include <string>`), then the compiler will choose the better matching overload.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. About the first question, I still have a doubt about the reason. Did you mean to say that adding a support for string literals in the ostream::operator<< would've been unnecessary?

Comment: I'm saying it would force unnecessary linkage to the string classes for all stream types. Even ones that don't need string handling. String handling is implemented as an addon using non-member operators, like any other user-defined class.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC the non-memberness of the `const char *` overloads was due to a technical reason: the committee wanted wide character streams to also provide `const char*` output, but if you provide both `operator<<(const charT*)` and `operator<<(const char *)` as members then the narrow character stream will be ill-formed for having two member functions with the same signature. Having them as nonmembers solves this problem - they will now just fight it out in overload resolution, and if there's an ambiguity, you just add a more specialized overload.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't there a member operator<< for the cout object which takes a const char[]?

There doesn't need to be, since `const char[]` will decay to `const char*`.

> Why isn't there a non-member operator<< which takes an integer?

Wouldn't this open us up to ambiguity during ADL?

> Why does cout << “hello” choose the non-member version of the operator<< ?

Because it's a better match than a conversion to `void const*`, which would require a type conversion.

Comment: Still not convinced about the first question-answer. You said const char[] decays to const char*. Yes, that's a well-known behaviour of an array decaying into a pointer. But the question is still the same _Why isn't there a member operator<< for the cout object which takes a const char*?_